# How to add rows based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm trying to add 10 rows based on a merchant_id in a table. This is the original table -

```
id    email    trend_type
1    abc@xyz.com 
2    cdsm@kcmd.com
```

And this is what I'm trying to create -

```
id    email    trend_type
1    abc@xyz.com   Bill 
1    abc@xyz.com   Visits
1    abc@xyz.com   Avg. Visits
1    abc@xyz.com   abc 
1    abc@xyz.com   mcd        
1    abc@xyz.com   mckfd      
1    abc@xyz.com   mfd        
1    abc@xyz.com   aps        
1    abc@xyz.com   mvmv       
1    abc@xyz.com   dep  
2    cdsm@kcmd.com Bill
2    cdsm@kcmd.com Visits    
.    .....         ...
.    .....         ...
```

I have 10 different trend types that I want to add to one id and email combination. I've created an array of all the trend types and I've tried using a nested for loop but I haven't been successful. Could really use some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
trends = ['Bill','Visits', 'Avg. Visits','abc',
          'mcd', 'mckfd', 'mfd', 'aps', 'mvmv', 'dep']

df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(trends))].assign(trend_type=trends * len(df))
print(df_new)

   id          email   trend_type
0   1    abc@xyz.com         Bill
0   1    abc@xyz.com       Visits
0   1    abc@xyz.com  Avg. Visits
0   1    abc@xyz.com          abc
0   1    abc@xyz.com          mcd
0   1    abc@xyz.com        mckfd
0   1    abc@xyz.com          mfd
0   1    abc@xyz.com          aps
0   1    abc@xyz.com         mvmv
0   1    abc@xyz.com          dep
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com         Bill
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com       Visits
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com  Avg. Visits
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com          abc
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com          mcd
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com        mckfd
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com          mfd
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com          aps
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com         mvmv
1   2  cdsm@kcmd.com          dep
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :

```
from  itertools import product

#add all types
types = ['Bill','Visits','Avg. Visits']
s = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.index, types))).set_index(0)[1].rename('trend_type')
df = df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   id          email   trend_type
0   1    abc@xyz.com         Bill
1   1    abc@xyz.com       Visits
2   1    abc@xyz.com  Avg. Visits
3   2  cdsm@kcmd.com         Bill
4   2  cdsm@kcmd.com       Visits
5   2  cdsm@kcmd.com  Avg. Visits
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use that kind of thing:

```
d = {'email':'blabla.bloblo@blublu.com',
    'trend_type':['bill','visits','abc', 'mcd', 'etc']}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

You will just have to add more entries in your dictionary and update the list of trends =)

I hope it will helps you!